# ReactJS: Nulled Object Are Still Being Called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use this library [scrolls.js](https://github.com/Pryme8/scrolls.js) to control my scroll animation. The problem is that when I route into other page, the callbacks from the disposed objects are still being called.

```
constructor(props) {
    this.flags = [];
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.scroll = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.flags.length; i++) {
        this.flags[i].callback = null; <-- Dispose the callback
        this.flags[i] = null; <-- Dispose the flag object
    }

    this.flags = null; <-- Dispose every flags
}
```

In the routed page, when I scroll the page, the callback is still being called, but because I have set it to null, it throws error. Then this means that the `flag` objects which have the callback are still alive.

This is the example of the object class:

```
export class Scroll {
    constructor() {
        this._lastPos = 0
        this._flags = []
        this._dead = false
        this.start()
    }
    ......

export class ScrollFlag {
    constructor(target, args = {}, parent) {
        this._parent = parent
        this._target = target
        args.start = args.start || 0
        args.duration = args.duration || 0
        args.callback = args.callback || function (value, target) { }
        args.debug = args.debug || false
        this._args = args;
        this._range = new Array(2)
        this.range[0] = args.start
        this.range[1] = this.range[0] + args.duration
        this._value = 0
        this._callback = args.callback
        ......
```

This is how I create the object:

```
createAnimationControl() {
    var that = this;
    let scrollHeight = document.getElementById('what-we-do-3D-scroll').scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
    let body = document.getElementById('body');

    this.flags.push(that.scroll.addFlag(body, {
        start: 0,
        duration: scrollHeight,
        callback: function (value, target) {
                let z = 0.7 * value;
                that.camera.setTarget(new window.BABYLON.Vector3(that.camera._target._x, that.camera._target._y, z));

                let v = (that.resizedZoom - 0.66) * value;
                that.camera.radius = that.resizedZoom - v;
        }
    }));

    this.flags.push(that.scroll.addFlag(body, {
        start: scrollHeight / 2,
        duration: 2 * scrollHeight / 3,
        callback: function (value, target) {
                document.getElementById('what-we-do-3D-overlay').style.opacity = value;
        }
    }));

    this.flags.push(that.scroll.addFlag(body, {
        start: scrollHeight - 30,
        duration: scrollHeight,
        callback: function (value, target) {
                document.getElementById('what-we-do-1st').style.opacity = value;
        }
    }));
}
```

How can I dispose it completely when routed to other page?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code, it seems the simplest solution is to tell the `Scroll` object that it's "dead":

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.scroll.dead = true;
}
```

This will [terminate](https://github.com/Pryme8/scrolls.js/blob/3e8eacb3b548396480599ad6f4f3debfd4235296/src/scrolls.js#L58) the `requestAnimationFrame` "loop" that this library is using.